# imagecreatetruecolor() makes my image lose quality

Tags: php, image

I'm using the script below to create an JPG based on people uploading an image. What happens is that even if an image is the exact same width/height it still loses quality so much that it's unacceptable.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['cpicture']['tmp_name']);
$thumb=imagecreatetruecolor(507,307);
ImageCopyResampled($thumb,$im,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,ImageSX($im),ImageSY($im));
ImagejpeG($thumb,"uploads/".$randomvalue.".jpg");
$imgurl="uploads/".$randomvalue.".jpg";
```

Are these functions reducing the quality?

Comment: Creative capitalization of function names there... :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg)'s third parameter is the quality of the image to be output:

> `quality` is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).

Try changing the relevant line of your code to:

```
ImagejpeG($thumb,"uploads/".$randomvalue.".jpg", 100);
```

Comment: It uploads much better. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden: Your post time: 2011-12-14 10:11:04Z. My post time: 2011-12-14 10:10:25Z. The revision history of my answer show I copied nobody.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson yes you did, you editted it some minutes afterwards.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden: No. See the revisions for my answer.http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/4460/revisions.png

Answer (score 0):

JPEG always loses quality because it is a lossy compressor.
If you don't want that, use e.g. png.
Yeah or set the quality of the output to 100:

```
ImagejpeG($thumb,"uploads/".$randomvalue.".jpg", 100);
```