# Function to resize jpg file compresses it too

Tags: php, image

I have a script which resizes images on server side before loading it to the client side.

Issue with this script is it compresses the file too, and that ends up in bad quality images.

Have a look at the script:

**Image_Resize.php**

```
var $image;
var $image_type;

function load($filename) {

  $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
  $this->image_type = $image_info[2];

  if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
  }
}
function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=0, $permissions=null) {

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,100);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image,$filename);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image,$filename);
  }
  if( $permissions != null) {

     chmod($filename,$permissions);
  }
}
function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image);
  }
}
function getWidth() {

  return imagesx($this->image);
}
function getHeight() {

  return imagesy($this->image);
}
function resizeToHeight($height) {

  $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function resizeToWidth($width) {
  $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
  $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function scale($scale) {
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
  $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function resize($width,$height) {
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  if ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG){
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
  }
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
}      
}
?>
```

**Photo.php**

```
<?php
require 'Image_Resize.php';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$imagenew=$_GET['id'];
$name=substr($imagenew,1);
if(file_exists($name)){
  $image = new ResizeImage();
  $image->load($imagenew);
  $image->resize($_GET['width'], $_GET['height']); //25-width, 30-height
  $image->output();
}
?>
```

I tried passing quality parameter to function `imagejpeg` in output function in Image_resize.php file. It's like this: `imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,100);`

But it's not working either(still outputs poor result than the original image). Anybody help?

Comment: is there any error when you apply that code?

Comment: *But it's not working either.* means what? no compression? no picture?

Comment: No error, just the quality is poorer than the original image

Comment: @donald123 It means it still outputs a poor result

Comment: try imagecreatetruecolor()

Comment: Instead of imagecopyresampled?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502683/imagecreatetruecolor-makes-my-image-lose-quality

Comment: I told in the question, I added `imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,100)` but it still outputs poor result. With or without it, no difference.